# How to save any value globally in the project so that we can access it from anywhere in react.js

Tags: reactjs

We need to save a value globally so we could access it from any component.
How can we do it properly?

I have tried it in many ways
1- make a component and store value in it. and import from other components where you need to use it
I have also tried props and state concept that would work in the parent-child flow of data.

Comment: Are you using redux ?

Answer (score 1):

-- Use Redux for easier state management for application-level state
-- use react store for component level state management

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use an external library you can just use the context of react. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

But when your application scales redux is probably the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a state manager like Redux or Mobx to manage your state outside of their component scope.